# Fastest way to search list of similar named images

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I have a website in which many users can upload their images (as many as they want). So my problem is the best way organizing this images.
Each user has their specific folder (path/username) but all the images go into the same folder (path/images) and at the moment I'm using the following system to organize the images:

```
$imagename = $userid.'-'.$imagenumber.'.jpg';
```

I need all images name since the page is displayed like the following:

```
<?php for ( $imagenumber ; $imagenumber < $numberofimages ; imagenumber++): ?>
<img scr="path/images/<?= $userid.'-'.$imagenumber ?>.jpg">
<?php endfor; ?>
```

My concern is if it is going to take much time to find all the images in the same folder when the number of images is too high, so I was wondering if I should create one image folder for each user and if it would be faster.
Thanks!

Comment: why you say will be slow find pictures?

Comment: Agree with Juan Carlos; what MySQL have you tried that is slow? Also, look up 'mysql index'.

Comment: if you know the user ($userid) you can have a field `maxNrImages` starts from 1 to n. Whenever a user uploads a file increment that field. Name the image file : `path/images/userid-1.jpg` etc.. Now you can do `$imagenumber =1; ... php for ( $imagenumber ; $imagenumber < $maxNrImages ; imagenumber++) ?>` Now you get all pictures from that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get beyond about 1000 files in a directory (folder) things start to get unwieldy.  You *can* store tens of thousands of file in a single directory on Linux, but that doesn't mean you *should*.

On Windows, there are some serious O(n) issues in looking things up in directories.

Your best bet is to organize your directory structure with a subfolder for each user. If you have tens of thousands of users you may want to organize a two-level subfolder setup.